# get a certain part of a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm converting a hashmap into 2 arrays, an integer array, and a String array. I'm trying to do this to make it usable, my HashMap looks like this:

`HashMap<String, String>` I'm converting the second string into an integer, and the hashmap is created from what the user puts into the configuration file.

I want to move the first string into an array, and then the second string into another array, how can  do that?

in otherwords, when i do hashmap.values() is there a way to get one section, like the first  and the the second one later? What's the best way around this?

Comment: Pleas show some code.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to move the first string into an array, and then the second
>   string into another array, how can do that?

```
List<String> keyList= new ArrayList<String>( map.keySet());
List<String> valueList= new ArrayList<String>( map.values());
```

If you want to convert List as array than,

```
 String[] keyArray=keyList.toArray(new String[keyList.size()]);
 String[] valueArray=valueList.toArray(new String[valueList.size()]);
```

Comment: List<String> keyList= new ArrayList<>( map.keySet()); wants me to add a cast?

Comment: Why it wants to cast? It is fine without cast.

Comment: I'm getting an error. Not sure why though.

Comment: What jdk version you used? If you use less than 1.7 than Diamond operator `<>` is not suppoted.

Comment: @Rmarmorstein, I have edited may answer without diamond operator. Now try.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you basically want to create two arrays one for `keys` and one for `values`. You can use `map.keySet()` to get `keys` and `map.values()` to get values. Now you can convert this two into a `List` or `Array`.